# Passing D3DFMT_UNKNOWN into IDirect3DDevice9::CreateTexture()

Tags: c++, directx, textures

I'm kind of wondering about this, if you create a texture in memory in DirectX with the CreateTexture function:

```
HRESULT CreateTexture(
  UINT Width,
  UINT Height,
  UINT Levels,
  DWORD Usage,
  D3DFORMAT Format,
  D3DPOOL Pool,
  IDirect3DTexture9** ppTexture,
  HANDLE* pSharedHandle
);
```

...and pass in `D3DFMT_UNKNOWN` format what is supposed to happen exactly? If I try to get the surface of the first or second level will it cause an error? Can it fail? Will the graphics device just choose a random format of its choosing? Could this cause problems between different graphics card models/brands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried it out and it does not fail, mostly

When `Usage` is set to `D3DUSAGE_RENDERTARGET` or `D3DUSAGE_DYNAMIC`, it consistently came out as `D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8`, no matter what I did to the back buffer format or other settings. I don't know if that has to do with my graphics card or not. My guess is that specifying unknown means, "pick for me", and that the 32-bit format is easiest for my card.

When the usage was `D3DUSAGE_DEPTHSTENCIL`, it failed consistently.

So my best conclusion is that specifying `D3DFMT_UNKNOWN` as the format gives DirectX the choice of what it should be. Or perhaps it always just defaults to `D3DFMT_A8R8G8B`.

Sadly, I can't confirm any of this in any documentation anywhere. :|

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb174363%28VS.85%29.aspx) doesn't say. But I'm pretty sure you'd get "D3DERR_INVALIDCALL" as a result.

> If the method succeeds, the return
>   value is D3D_OK. If the method fails,
>   the return value can be one of the
>   following: D3DERR_INVALIDCALL,
>   D3DERR_OUTOFVIDEOMEMORY,
>   E_OUTOFMEMORY.

Comment: No, I tried it and it does not fail, at least not in all cases.

Comment: Ok, at this point it would be worth letting us know what you expect to happen, and what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think this falls into the "undefined" category.  Some drivers will fail the allocations, while others may default to something.  I've never seen anything in the WDK that says that this condition needs to be handled.  I'm guessing if you enable the debug DX runtime you will see an error message.